# How should I denote variable(s) in a matrix?

Tags: matrices

I want to define the following matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix} x \cos\phi - y \sin\phi \\[4px] x \sin\phi + y \cos\phi\end{bmatrix}$$
Would it be better to call it $A(\phi)$ or $A_\phi$? I'm not too sure because I know for a fact that we use parenthesis with functions (such as $f(x)$ instead of $f_x$), but I'm also pretty sure I've seen people using the latter for matrices...

Given that $x, y$ are used as coordinates (yes this is the result of rotating $\begin{bmatrix} x \\[4px] y \end{bmatrix}$ by an angle $\phi$ around the origin), would it make more sense to maybe instead write $A_\phi(x, y)$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $A_\phi(x, y)$, $A(x, y, \phi)$, $A(y, \phi, x)$, $A(x, y; \phi)$, $A_{x,y}(\phi)$ are all correct and generally acceptable names to give this function of $x, y, \phi$. Variables can be dropped too, if they are clear from context (e.g. $A(\phi)$, $A_x(y)$ or even just $A$), though it can make substituting specific values a little clunky. As for what you *should* do, it depends on the context. Where are you using this matrix?

Comment: Sometimes the minimal notation is the most elegant. If you only want to stress, say, the dependence on $\phi$, then $A_{\phi}$ is much better than all of the above variants (in particular if you use them hundred times afterwards. I will save you almost one page then).

Comment: Thanks! I understand what to do now :)
I'm planning to use the matrix just as a shorthand for future matrices denoting translations of any given point $(x, y)$ by an angle $\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your matrix is the expanded matrix product

$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos \phi & -\sin \phi \\ \sin \phi & \cos \phi \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$$

in which case the dependence on $\phi$ is the most important factor (in my eyes). If you want to study the matrix itself, you might write $A(\phi)$ (and then to apply the matrix to a vector, write something like $A(\phi)[x \ y]^T$). In another case, you might write $A_\phi(x,y)$ if you conceptualize $A$ as a transformation with input $(x,y)$. Ultimately there is not a "correct" notation, but it depends on what it is you want to emphasize or study, as well as clarity, readability, convention, etc (as observed by the comments).

It might even be natural to write something like $A^\phi$, with the index in the superscript. This is because the collection of all rotation matrices forms a group under multiplication (or composition, if you consider them as transformations rather than matrices), obeying

$$A^\phi \cdot A^\theta = A^{\phi + \theta}$$

which is analogous to exponent rules. But this also might conflict with already established notation for matrix exponents.

Comment: i'm surprised you managed to guess what i was doing just by reading my question :O
well, you're totally right that I'm trying to conceptualize A as a transformation with input (x, y), but with it written in the form of a matrix. I've decided to settle on $A_\phi$ for now, though. thanks!